# javascript retrieve class names from multiple elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this in my page:

```
 <div id="container">

        <div>
            <p>...</p>
            <a href="#" class></a>
        </div>  

        <div>
            <p>...</p>
            <a href="#" class="checked"></a>
        </div>  

        <div>
            <p>...</p>
            <a href="#" class></a>
        </div>  

</div>
```

Now, I want some codes to execute when each of the a elements changes its class. This doesn't work:

```
$('#food_container').click( function() {

    if ($('#food_container a').attr('class') == "checked") {
        /* some codes */
    }

});
```

How to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to check when *any* element has the class, or when *all* of them do?

Comment: Use `.hasClass('checked')` to check if the element has the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.hasClass()` to see if *any* of the elements have the class:

```
if ($('#container a').hasClass('checked')) {
  // ...
```

To see if *all* of them have the class:

```
if ($('#container a').length =  $('#container a.checked').length) {
  // ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using wrong *id* in the selector. Change

```
$('#food_container').click( function() {

   if ($('#food_container a').attr('class') == "checked") {
    /* some codes */
   }

});
```

to

```
$('#container').click( function() {

   if ($('#container a').hasClass('checked')) {
    /* some codes */
   }

});
```

Comment: What if the element has two classes?  Checking the "class" attribute directly is usually not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
var links = $("#container").children("a");
$(links).each(function(i,v){
  if($(this).hasClass("checked")){

  }
});
```